Film where markings appear on a boys body?
I watched a film a while ago, I don't remember much but it was based on a boy who had markings of some kind on his body. 
He dies in it.
He goes to a house which I think was haunted with either a teacher of his or an older woman. 
The film begins if my memory serves me correctly with him sitting in a cafe with markings on his body and face with his hood up. Not the best description but any suggestions would be well appreciated as it's been bugging me for ages!

I assume you mean he dies in the haunted house? Was it color? Television? How long is "a while"?

Really long shot, but based only on 'boy in hoodie with marks on his face', perhaps Beastly?

From caption there was Omen, but then I read the body ... :) Do you recall what sort of markings? Do you recall approximately when you saw it (to narrow down timeframe – also if it was DVD/VHS/TV/Cinema/etc.). Do you recall anything that can further help narrow down timeframe: such as cars, cellphones, etc. As he had a hoodie it should at least be 1970+. Do you recall anything that can help giving it a location like city, country etc.

The boy is killed by a man not in the house. It was approximately two years ago and I watched it on sky. It was quite a recent film.

Sounds like Book of Blood (2009). 

A hooded, disfigured young man is eating at a diner, being watched by a stranger. The stranger is Wyburd (Clive Russell), who has been stalking the young man, Simon (Jonas Armstrong). Wyburd convinces Simon to join him in his truck, where Simon passes out and awakens strapped to a table. Wyburd offers him a choice: a slow death, or a quick and clean death by telling the story of the Book of Blood, a series of scars and inscriptions carved on Simon from head to toe. Opting for a clean death, Simon reveals his story. — Wikipedia 

Here is a screen cap I found on the internet of him sitting in the diner. 


Looks good too. Keira, do either of the movies suggested here ring a bell?

Book of Blood rings a bell but there are bits of the trailer that I don't remember. I'll have to watch it to see if it's the one. Thank you!

@Keira, I've seen the movie twice and there is a lot of the trailer I don't even remember.

OK, Heartless from 2009 could definitely be it. It's about a young man with marks on his face and body who always wears a hood. At some point he goes into a house and makes a sordid deal with an older man to removes his marks, and another man kills him in the end of the film, outside the house. Here's the trailer.
